# When pickling a class I get different behavior in python that in cython

Tags: python, import, pickle, cython

I have the following file hierarchy:

```
python/apps/A.py
      /geometrylib/__init__.py
      /geometrylib/B.py
      /geometrylib/geometry.py
      /geometrylib/goemetry.pyx
      /geometrylib/goemetry.pyd
```

geometry.pyx and geometry.py contain the same class Camera (the cython version defines the class with cdef ). Both A.py and B.py import the geometry module.

If I import the cython version(compiled to geometry.pyd), I can correctly pickle Camera from within B.py in the python/geometrylib folder. But I can't pickle Camera from A.py in the python/apps folder, I get the following exception:

pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not found as geometry.Camera

However, if I delete the geometry.pyd and I import the python version(geometry.py) instead, then I can pickle Camera from either A.py or B.py. Nothing else changes apart from deleting geometry.pyd, same python command line, run from the same folder in both cases.
**why this difference?**

Digging a bit I see that the exception occurs in C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py line 742

```
try:
    __import__(module)            #line 742
    mod = sys.modules[module]
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
except (ImportError, KeyError, AttributeError):
    raise PicklingError(
        "Can't pickle %r: it's not found as %s.%s" %
        (obj, module, name))
```

When in A.py I import the cython version(geometry.pyd), (and I pickle a Camera instance to trigger the expection) module is "geometry" and `__import__(module)` triggers the exception. When in A.py I import the python version(geometry.py),(and I pickle a Camera instance to trigger the expection) module is "geometrylib.geometry" and `__import__(module)` imports the module correctly.

I have solved the problem by adding python/geometrylib to PYTHONPATH, then I can correctly pickle Camera from both A.py and B.py using the cython version.

**Is this how is it supposed to work?** I don't like my solution. **Does anybody have a better solution?**

EDITED to add some extra information.

Also, by request, this is the setup.py I used to build the cython extension.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy

setup(
    cmdclass = { 'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("geometry", ['geometry.pyx'], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), "."])])
```

Comment: What does the Python command line look when you execute the Cython version vs. the pure Python version? In what directory do you execute the Python command?

Comment: [accidentally hit enter without finishing]

How are you compiling the Cython module?

Remember: Cython files are compiled into a different directory usually, so you need to tell it where to find the rest of the modules being imported. Perhaps you can do this as part of `setup.py`, but honestly I cannot tell you without any additional info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are building geometry.pyx as a top-level module, while in fact it is part of `geometrylib` package. As a result, `Camera` class gets assigned incorrect `__module__` value (`geometry` instead of `geometrylib.geometry`) and pickler fails when it tries to find top-level module named `geometry`.

You should follow standard packaging guidelines, i.e. put setup.py into "Python" folder, next to the top-level module (geometrylib). setup call will look like this:

```
setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("geometrylib.geometry", ['geometrylib/geometry.pyx'], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), "."])])
```

Comment: This solves the problem! I didn't know that that was the standard packaging guideline, I'll to read them!