# Cython Pickling in Package "not found as" Error

Tags: python, pickle, cython

I'm having trouble pickling a Cython class, but only when it's defined inside a package. This problem was noted [previously online](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cython-users/efRRFJVuZh8/x2-R8qHBlCkJ), but they didn't state how it was resolved. There are two components here: the Cython pickling using a `__reduce__` method and a package error.

## Cython Pickling Success

I'll first show how it works without the package part. This example works correctly.

### Cython File

My Cython file is `reudce.pyx`:

```
cdef class Foo(object):
    cdef int n

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __reduce__(self):
        return Foo, (self.n,)
```

### Setup File

This may be compiled with a `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("reduce", ["reduce.pyx"])]
)
```

by executing `python setup.py build && cp build/lib*/reduce.so .`

### Test Script

The test script is called `test_reduce.py` and is:

```
import reduce
import pickle
f = reduce.Foo(4)
print pickle.dumps(f)
```

Executing `python test_reduce.py` works fine.

## Cython Pickling in Package Failure

However, once the `reduce.pyx` is put into a package, there is an error.

### Package Creation

To reproduce this, first create a package called `bar`.

```
mkdir bar
mv reduce.so bar
echo "from reduce import Foo" > bar/__init__.py
```

### Test Script

Change the `test_reduce.py` file to be:

```
import bar
import pickle
f = bar.Foo(4)
print pickle.dumps(f)
```

### Error Message

Running `python test_reduce.py` gives the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
  (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'reduce.Foo'>: it's not found as reduce.Foo
```

There is a catch of errors which are all turned into a PicklingError in `pickle.py` After looking at that code, the specific error which is occuring is:

```
ImportError: No module named reduce
```

### Sanity Test

To check that there is not some kind of scope or other issue, if I run the steps which the pickle module should execute, everything works:

```
f = bar.Foo(4)
call, args = f.__reduce__()
print call(*args)
```

So what's going on here?!

Comment: Check this answer to the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16405319/204882. Basically, you can't just move the compiled extension around. Package name has to be specified at build time.

Comment: Huh, that worked. I guess didn't really understand how the Extension object in the setup.py works. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in the build script. The `Pickle` module uses the `__module__` attribute of a function/class for pickling. That `__module__` attribute comes from the first argument to the `Extension()` constructor in the `setup.py` script. Since I defined my constructor to be `Extension('reduce', ['reduce.pyx'])`, the `__module__` attribute is `reduce`. It should be `bar/reduce` though since it's now in a package.

Making `setup.py` look like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension('bar/reduce', ['reduce.pyx'])]
)
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

maybe something like this is possible: `Foo.__module__ = 'bar.reduce'` in `bar/__init__.py`

Or you can use the module `copyreg`. Here are some snippets from the code of copyreg:

```
"""Helper to provide extensibility for pickle.

This is only useful to add pickle support for extension types defined in
C, not for instances of user-defined classes.
"""

def pickle(ob_type, pickle_function, constructor_ob=None):
    # ...

# Example: provide pickling support for complex numbers.

try:
    complex
except NameError:
    pass
else:

    def pickle_complex(c):
        return complex, (c.real, c.imag)

    pickle(complex, pickle_complex, complex)
```

**OLD VERSION**

Pickle does this:

```
    try:
        __import__(module, level=0)
        mod = sys.modules[module]
        klass = getattr(mod, name)
    except (ImportError, KeyError, AttributeError):
        raise PicklingError(
            "Can't pickle %r: it's not found as %s.%s" %
            (obj, module, name))
```

Can you try out which line fails?

When pickle piclkes classes and functions like `module.function` it reasssures itself that this is the right function meant:

```
# module.py
def function(): # 1
    pass
a = function
def function(): # 2
    pass
```

Function 1 in `a` can not be pickled but function 2 can be pickled because it is found in the module under the `__name__` it has which is "function".

So in your case pickle does not find the same class `Foo` in the `reduce` module as is passed as argument. The argument `Foo` claims to be found in the module `reduce`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my question. I found it is actually an import error. I've updated my question. It says there is no module called reduce. Just to be clear, if I don't use cython this example works correctly.

Comment: I added some noteworthy details about copyreg that is used by pickle.

Comment: The first suggestion would solve the problem, but it's not possible to set static attributes of extension types. If you try it, you can a TypeError. It might be possible to accomplish that behavior by following the example in [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735051/share-extension-types-in-cython-for-static-typing) where a static attribute is defined on an extension type. It looks just as complicated as mine though.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the copyreg one. Could you give a snippet for how it would work in `reduce.pyx`?

Comment: It should work like with `complex` - replacing `complex` with `Foo` should be enough. `__reduce__` should not be required then.