# Functions defined in Cython .pyx become built-in?

Tags: python, namespaces, cython, pickle

I was playing with the cython tutorial (http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html)

And I have a directory like so:

```
somedir/ExampleCython.py
somedir/fib.pyx
somedir/fib.so
somedir/function_file.py
somedir/setup.py
```

Where the fib.pyx defines the function fib from the cython tutorial linked above, function_file.py contains the following definition:

```
def moopy(param):
    param += 1
    return param
```

and ExampleCython.py contains the following:

```
import fib as moo

print moo.fib

from function_file import moopy

print moopy
```

I build the fib.so using python setup.py build_ext --inplace, then I run python ExampleCython.py and I get the following output:

```
<built-in function fib>
<function moopy at 0x1002b4398>
```

Now, I know there is no python built-in called fib, and just to test I tried changing the name 'fib' to something silly like 'poopypants' and it still says it's built-in.  What is happening to the namespace of the fib function?  I have this issue in a much larger block of code elsewhere which is preventing me from pickling a class I created - pickle complains that it can't find my function in the module it belongs to - but I figured I'd simplify it for the question here.

For reference - python 2.7.11/cython 0.26 on OSX 10.12.6

Comment: "built-in" is misleading - it just means that it's a function implemented in a C library (as you'd expect from Cython). You're probably better creating a [mcve] that illustrates your pickle problem (which seems to be what you're really trying to solve)

Comment: ok, what should I do to this question then?  edit it with an updated example, or close it or mark it answered or something?

Comment: I'd edit this question. Since nobody's answered it I don't think it's a problem to make a reasonably big edit to it. (Your choice though - both options are reasonable!)

Comment: I actually solved my pickle issue based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503466/cython-pickling-in-package-not-found-as-error?rq=1

Though it seems to me the answer to my question here is just as you said 'built-in is misleading', the objects still have the correct '____module____' attributes for example.  Can I mark your comment as the accepted answer somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved in a comment but posted as an answer for completeness:

Python is describing the functions as "built-in function" purely to mean that it's compiled in C, rather than meaning that it's a standard library function, and so there was issue with this - the correct function was being found in the correct module.

On my PC it appears as `<cyfunction module.function_name at 0xsome_address>` which is a more helpful message. I think this might be a Python 3 improvement (but I'm not 100% sure).